# How to use the Data side filter on Custom Type in Purview

Tags: azure-purview

We have created 3 custom EntityTypeDefs and the related AtlasEntities

```
`EntityTypeDef Database superTypes=["azure_resource"]
`EntityTypeDef Schema superTypes=["Asset"]
`EntityTypeDef Table superTypes=["DataSet"]`
```

The Columns are connected to the Table via tabular_schema and the various assets are connected via RelationshipTypeDef.

Defining the types in this way we are unable to use the Data filter in the left menu. Is there a specific way to define custom types and assets so that I can use this filter (Database, File, Report, Table...)?

Comment: To enable the Data filter in the left menu for your custom types and assets, you need to define them as subtypes of the built-in DataSet type

Comment: Hi @Aswin I tried using subtypes ( EntityTypeDef(superTypes=["DataSet"], subTypes=["Folder"]) ) but the filter still doesn't work. Do you have an example to share? Thanks a lot Diego